# __attribute_warn_unused_result__ vs __attribute__((warn_unused_result))

Tags: c

Been using `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` with joy for a while in some new project. I have been coding using Vim.

Now I'm starting to use KDevelop sometimes when developing that same project, and there is an autocomplete `__attribute_warn_unused_result__` (among others) as well as `__attribute__` which I was using.

Are those two `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` and `__attribute_warn_unused_result__` the same? Is any of those supposed to supersede the other? I realized that, when editing headers (`*.h`), the autocomplete feature suggests both alternatives, but that, when editing sources (`*.c`), the feature only suggests `__attribute_warn_unused_result__`.

Comment: It could be an intrinsic for `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`. Do you have any chance to go to the definition of `__attribute_warn_unused_result__`. It could be something like `#define __attribute_warn_unused_result__ __attribute__((warn_unused_result))`.

Comment: What's an intrinsic..?

Comment: intrinsic is a compiler specific directive that used for optimization or readability. For example, `__asm` is an intrinsic of GCC to use inline assembly or `__bis_SR_register` is an intrinsic of most TI products that used to access `SR` register of processor. Those operations cannot be done with pure C and needs some compiler help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC supports this attribute since 3.4 so that `__attribute_warn_unused_result__` defined as `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` or empty depend on GCC version (see `sys/cdefs.h`).

Search `__attribute_warn_unused_result__` definition in your programming system.

**Update:**

Attribute `warn_unused_result` is a feature of the compiler.
Any GCC compiler since 3.4 will recognize and use `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`.
But this feature may not be supported by other compilers or may be specified otherwise.

On the other hand, the `__attribute_warn_unused_result__` macro defined in library header file.
Purposes — the ability to remove an attribute for non-supported compilers; the hide implementation details and specify this property in another way.

But this macro depends on library implementation.
For example, the macro not present at all in arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.9.3 and avr-gcc 4.9.2 packages, just as in mingw32-gcc 3.4.2 which I still use for one "ancient" project.

For gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-eabi similar purpose macros defined as

```
#define __result_use_check  __attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))
```

But in gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf package the definition (a whole sys/cdefs.h file) is the same as for "native" gcc in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
#define __attribute_warn_unused_result__ \
    __attribute__ ((__warn_unused_result__))
```

Hence, which one approach supercedes another one depends on the goals.
On my opinion:

- For code that supposed to be used with GCC (>= 3.4) across a couple of platforms it is better to use explicit `__attribute__((__warn_unused_result__))`.
- For code that supposed to be compiled by a couple of compilers that may not support this feature or may support it in different way it is better to use some macro (may be even self-defined).
- For already existing project it is better to use the approach mostly used in present code :-)

About autocompletion with different behavior for header and source files.
I don't know. May be it is just originality of specific IDE (autocompletion).

Comment: The important part, which you left out, is "by this specific implementation".

Comment: @Deduplicator You are right. I assume GCC although this question is not narrowed to.

Comment: I up voted this, but I can't accept the answer if you don't answer every question or if I fork the question in two simpler questions.

Comment: @uprego I expanded my answer as good as I can. Thanks for good question that involves me to deeper investigation of this problem.

Comment: I normally recap this project from time to time on macOS (where I have some weird aversion to use a _local_ compiler instead of that shipped by vendor). It seems to me Clang was not accepting `__attribute_warn_unused_result__`. I'm noob at this platform and I don't really know how to quickly check for system headers here. Anyway, as long as `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` seems more widely supported, my doubts are no longer important and my questions rest answered or unimportant.

Comment: (If anyone knows of some prominent compiler strongly offended by `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`, you are welcome to drop a line :P)

Comment: @uprego some good proprietary C/C++ compilers for embedded (e.g. IAR) does not know about `__attribute__` at all. IAR uses separate keywords like `__packed`, `__noreturn` and `#pragma` like `#pragma location=XXX` instead of `__section__` attribute.